# JQuery disable link in table row

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

My jQuery is not working as expected:

I am trying to loop through each row then loop through each td and check if a td in a row contains the text 'test1' if so I need disable the link defined in a td with class "ms-vb-icon2" within the same row.

```
$("tr:has(td:contains('test1')) td.ms-vb-icon.a#click").click(function() { return false; });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R8fuR/

My code is as below...

```
<table class='ms-listviewtable'>
<tr>
<td class='ms-vb2-icon'>
<A onclick='GoToLink(this);return false;' href='http://www.google.com' target='_self'><IMG alt='Edit' src='http://web-hub.net/wiki/skins/largepublisher/icon_edit_small.gif'/></A>
</td>
<td class='ms-vb2'></td>
<td class='ms-vb2'></td>
<td class='ms-vb2'></td>
<td class='ms-vb2'></td>
<td class='ms-vb2'>test1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='ms-vb2-icon'>
<A onclick='GoToLink(this);return false;' href='http://www.google.com' target='_self'><IMG alt='Edit' src='http://web-hub.net/wiki/skins/largepublisher/icon_edit_small.gif'/></A>
</td>
<td class='ms-vb2'></td>
<td class='ms-vb2'></td>
<td class='ms-vb2'></td>
<td class='ms-vb2'></td>
<td class='ms-vb2'>test2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='ms-vb2-icon'>
<A onclick='GoToLink(this);return false;' href='http://www.google.com' target='_self'><IMG alt='Edit' src='http://web-hub.net/wiki/skins/largepublisher/icon_edit_small.gif'/></A>
</td>
<td class='ms-vb2'></td>
<td class='ms-vb2'></td>
<td class='ms-vb2'></td>
<td class='ms-vb2'></td>
<td class='ms-vb2'>test3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case remove the `.`, the `#click` and add the missing `2` to the `vb2`, like this:

```
$("tr:has(td:contains('test1')) td.ms-vb2-icon a").click(function() { return false; });
```

Or alternatively, remove the initial click handler, this seems to be more what you're after:

```
$("tr:has(td:contains('test1')) td.ms-vb2-icon a")
  .removeAttr('onclick').click(function() { return false; });
```

[You can try out a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/R8fuR/2/)

You need to remove the already attached event handler because it'll happen *before* this new one, since it was attached first.  The `.` comes out because it's not a class, it's a child element, and the `#click` comes out because we're not looking for an `<a id="click">`.  I think what you intended here was `a[onclick]`, the [has-attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/), but since there's only one link there's no need for that here :)

Comment: Thanks Nick, though it doesn't seem to disable the google link in firefox http://jsfiddle.net/R8fuR/1/

Comment: @nav - 2 things, you weren't including jQuery, and there's a missing `2` on the vb2, to eliminate another error we can remove that `onclick` attribute, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/R8fuR/2/ I'll update the answer to match.

Answer (score 0):

In your selector there is an extra dot between the td class and the anchor. Try:

```
$("tr:has(td:contains('test1')) td.ms-vb-icon a#click").click(function() { return false; });
```

Answer (score 0):

should look like:

```
$('table.ms-listviewtable > tbody').find('td').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   if(/test1/.test($this.text())){
      $this.siblings('.ms-vb-icon2').find('a')
         .unbind('click')
         .removeAttr('onclick')
         .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   }
});
```